IPhO2014 T1 with Lagrange multipliers
I'm trying to solve IPhO2014 Problem 1 with the method of Lagrange multipliers and I'm facing some problems.

I choose the origin to be at the center of the cylinder, and use three coordinates: $(x, y)$ the position of the pluck, and $d$, the horizontal position of the center of the cylinder.
It appears to me the Lagrangian is
$$\mathcal L = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2) + \frac{1}{2}M\dot{d}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2 - mgy = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2) + M\dot{d}^2 - mgy$$
where $I=MR^2$ is the moment of inertia of the cylinder, $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the cylinder, and I use the non-slipping condition to get $\dot{d} = \omega R$.
And it appears to be the constraint is
$$g = (x-d)^2+y^2-R^2=0$$
So Euler-Lagrange equations give:
$$\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt}\big(\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial \dot x}\big) + \lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = -m\ddot{x}+2 \lambda (x-d) = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dt}\big(\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial \dot y}\big) + \lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = -mgy -m\ddot{y}+2 \lambda y = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial d} - \frac{d}{dt}\big(\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial \dot d}\big) + \lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial d} = -M\ddot{d}-2 \lambda (x-d) = 0$$
Then the target is to solve for $\lambda$ when $y=-R$, but I cannot seem to get further. Am I in the right direction? Or maybe it's too hard to solve this problem in this way? As a reference, the solution can be found here: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/physprob.com/files/ipho/2014_Kazakhstan_p1Sol.pdf

To solve for the unknows $~\ddot x~,\ddot y,\ddot d~,\lambda~$
you need additional equation which come from the constraint equation
$$ g=(x-d)^2+y^2-R^2=0$$
from here
$$\ddot g=(x-d)\ddot x+y\,\ddot y-(x-d)\ddot d+(\dot x-\dot d
)^2+\dot y^2=0$$
